# A twisted inner class in Java

Tags: java, inner-classes

The following program uses an inner class named `Anonymous` which itself extends its enclosing class `Main`.

```
package name;

public class Main
{
    private final String name;

    Main(String name)
    {
        this.name = name;
    }

    private String name()
    {
        return name;
    }

    private void reproduce()
    {
        new Anonymous().printName();
    }

    private class Anonymous extends Main
    {
        public Anonymous()
        {
            super("reproduce");
        }

        public void printName()
        {
            System.out.println(name());
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
       new Main("main").reproduce();
    }
}
```

---

The only statement in the main() method invokes the constructor of the outer class `Main` supplying a string **main** and just then the method `reproduce()` is being called.

---

The `reproduce method` contains the statement `new Anonymous().printName();` which invokes the `printName()` method on the `Anonymous` class object. The `super();` constructor is supplying a new string **reproduce** to its enclosing super class `Main`.

---

Accordingly, the statement within the `printName` method `System.out.println(name());` should display the string **reproduce** rather than **main** but it always displays the string **main**. Why is it so?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Because you've declared `Main.name()` as `private`, so it's not visible as a superclass method.  It is, however, visible as a method of `Anonymous`'s enclosing class, so it is invoked on the enclosing object.

So if you declare `Main.name()` as `public` or `protected`, you will indeed see `"reproduce"`.
Alternatively, if you declare `Anonymous` as `static`, it no longer compiles.